# Posting data to index,php file on a server ip

Tags: php

i am trying to capture some data from a IOT device. The problem isto capture the data you have to feed in the ip to the device so that data is [posted to that ip address.

To process the data,i came up with this script and aptly named it `index.php`

```
<?php
$servername = "94.049.947.776";
$username = "droid";
$password = "!@nord";
$dbname = "atree";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
$data = $_POST;
$sql = "INSERT INTO gps (data)
VALUES ('$data')";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();
?>
```

To test it out,i have this html page

```
<form method="post" action="972.245.119.017">
<input type="text" name="ed" value="jsonstring" />
<input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

However,no data is inserted to the database. What could be wrong with my script?.

Comment: Do you have any error??

Comment: Firebug does not seem to report any.

Comment: I have never seen `action=""` with ip why not index.php and `$data` is not a string you need to get the input value

Comment: `$_POST` is array, All you can insert in your case is `array` string.

Comment: @meda really? that's strange. i though it would work.

Comment: @u_mulder i did this `$data = json_encode($_POST);` so there is no doubt.

Comment: worried about sql injection? you should be

Comment: Is it possible to receive arbitrary post data from any connected client on lets say public ip: 80?

Comment: So you said, you use a device for sending data??  Is it have a browser??

Answer (score 0):

`$_POST` is php variable in form of an Array, maybe try to :

replace :

```
$data = $_POST;
```

with :

```
$data = $_POST['ed']; // the value from the form
```

or some other value that you posted to the index.php like :

```
$data = $_POST['VALUE_NAME'];
```

consider working with PDO (http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) for the sql part

Answer (score 0):

You should replace :

```
$data = $_POST;
```

by :

```
$data=$_POST['ed'];
```